# PostgreSQL or DBMS question. Is this a physical or logical schema?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgis, rdbms

The schema of the database is shown below:

Country

```
name: varchar (35)
cont: varchar (35)
pop: real
GDP: real
life_exp: real
shape: char(15)
```

City

```
name: varchar (35)
country: varchar(35)
pop: real
capital: char(1)
shape: char (15)
```

River

```
name: varchar(35)
origin: varchar(35)
length: integer
shape: char(15)
```

I think it is a logical/conceptual schema but the person who graded my assignment said it was a physical schema.  I thought physical schema referred to specific hardware,software,file paths etc.  The logical schema is mapped to the physical schema usually in some sort of table format.  Am I right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between logical schema and physical schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067378/what-is-the-difference-between-logical-schema-and-physical-schema)

Comment: A logical database schema would be free of implementation details. As soon as you mention `varchar`, you've tied yourself to SQL. There are other options out there.